# Image hosted on S3 has CORS error only on Android chrome

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, amazon-s3, cors

I have an Amazon S3 bucket setup to serve static image files, for example:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-uploaded-files/images/cat.jpg

[image: cat]

As you can see, the file hosting and URL work fine. I have everything set to public, and I also have a CORS configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I also have a webpage hosted on GitHub Pages that uses JavaScript to fetch an image, display it, and do some processing of the underlying image data. Here's a simplified example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>S3 Image Test</title>
    <script>
    function loadImage(){
      var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
      var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      var image = new Image();
      image.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
        console.log('data: ' + imageData);
      };
      image.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
      image.src = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-uploaded-files/images/cat.jpg';
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="loadImage()">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" style="width: 500px; height:500px;"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

On my Windows laptop in both Chrome and Internet Explorer, this works fine. I see the image in the browser, and I see the image data being printed to the console.

However, if I open the URL in Android Chrome, I just get a blank screen. If I hook my phone up to Android Studio and look at Logcat, I see this error:

```
07-14 18:45:16.797 14951-14951/? I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Access to Image at 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-uploaded-files/images/cat.jpg' from origin 'http://kevinworkman.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://kevinworkman.com' is therefore not allowed access.", source: http://kevinworkman.com/GitHubPagesTest/ (0)
```

I understand what this error normally means, but I've confirmed that my CORS configuration is correct, and it works in other browsers.

I've tried it on two different Android devices (a Pixel 1 and Pixel 2), and they both show the same behavior. I've tried it over both `http` and `https`, and I see the same behavior with both.

It also works fine in Android Firefox.

I'm not using cloudflare or a CDN or anything.

**Is something wrong with my configuration? Is there a reason Android Chrome is behaving differently from other browsers?**

I'd also be curious to hear from users with iOS devices since I haven't been able to test with those.

Comment: This must be caused by the different CORS policy of the two browsers. I get exactly the same result (error message and picture not loading) like you get on chrome mobile **also with chrome desktop** (Version 67.0.3396.99, Windows 7). I didn't ever change something at the Chrome configuration. In Firefox everything works perfect. I compared both Headers in Chrome and Firefox and they are exactly the same `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`. There are only 2 differences in Chrome: 1. Chrome shows up two network requests: One for the image and one for the page and Firefox only one 2. Firefox Status C